# Prompt when click on a link and modify it

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink, prompt

I have a link on my page and i want that on click an prompt will show, i'll write there something and then it will change the href of the link and move on the page. But i have something like this:

```
var link="index.php?s=podporaf&act=close";
function editLink() {
var x = prompt("Note":, ""); 
link+="&note=" + x;

window.location=link;
```

And then link:

```
<a onclick="editLink()"  href="#">Close</a>
```

All i want is before going to the page change the href to

```
href="index.php?s=podporaf&act=close&note=something"
```

And then go on that page. So I have two questions. Is it even possible? And if so then how? My solution does not work, it just goes follow the link, but the prompt does not show.

Comment: `prompt("Note":, "");` is a syntax error. The : is in the wrong place. `prompt("Note:", "");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`prompt("Note":, "");` is a syntax error. The `:` is in the wrong place.

```
prompt("Note:", "");
```

Also, make sure that `editLink` is defined before your `<a>` is defined. So put your `<script>` in the `<head>` of the page.

Comment: Ok, got it, I missed that colon, it's woking now. Thanks